# MongoError: cursor does not exist, was killed or timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when I am trying to read a large number of record I am getting following error.

> MongoError: cursor does not exist, was killed or timed out

my code

```
   let cursor =  Transaction.find(query,{},{timeout: true}).cursor()
    cursor.eachAsync((tx) => {
        console.log('tx', tx);
        dataSet.push(tx);
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('dataset',dataSet)
        resolve(dataSet);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error in query: ", err.message," error code:",err.code);
        reject(apiError('KFWE0001'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
Transaction.find(query,{},{timeout: false}).cursor()
```

Comment: mind explaining why this fixes the original question?